Proving $\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^4 - y^4}{x^3 - y^3} = 0$
Let $f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^4 - y^4}{x^3 - y^3}$ be defined in $U = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x, x) \colon x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. I have to determine $\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} f(x, y)$ by $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.
I know that if $(x, y) \in U$, then $\dfrac{x^4 - y^4}{x^3 - y^3} = \frac{(x - y)(x + y)(x^2 + y^2)}{(x - y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)} = \frac{(x + y)(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + xy + y^2}.$
Now I got stuck...

Hint: $1+z+z^2\ge 3/4$

If $x,y\in\Bbb R$, $x^2+xy+y^2=\frac12\left(x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2\right)\geqslant\frac12(x^2+y^2)$, and therefore, if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$,$$\left|\frac{(x+y)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}\right|\leqslant2|x+y|.$$So,$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x+y)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}=0.$$

$\frac{(x+y)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}\leqslant2(x+y)$ should be $\frac{|x+y|(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}\leqslant2|x+y|$.

@Riemann I've edited my answer. Thank you.

@
José Carlos Santos Nice answer!

If $x=\rho\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta$, then
$$
\frac{(x+y)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}=\rho\frac{\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}.
$$
But it's not hard to prove that, for each $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\left|\frac{\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}\right|\le1$:
\begin{align}
(1+\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2&=1+2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\\
&\ge1+2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\\
&=(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))^2.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
\left|\frac{(x+y)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}\right|\le\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x+y)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}=0.
$$

The inequality can also be established using Cartesian coordinates alone: \begin{align}
(x^2+xy+y^2)^2
&=(\rho^2+x y)^2\
&=\rho^4+2\rho^2 x y+x^2 y^2\
&\geq \rho^4+2\rho^2 x y\
&= \rho^2(\rho^2+2 x y)\
&=(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2+2xy)=\rho^2(x+y)^2
\end{align}

Alternatively, in one line: $$(x^2 ++y^2+ x y)^2-(x y)^2=(x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2$$

Observe
$$
\begin{align}
\left| \frac {{x}^{2} + {y}^{2}}{{x}^{2} - x y + {y}^{2}} \right|
& = \left| 1 + \frac {x y}{{x}^{2} - x y + {y}^{2}} \right| \\
& \le 1 + \left| \frac {x y}{{x}^{2} - x y + {y}^{2}} \right| \\
& = 1 + {\left| \frac {x}{y} - 1 + \frac {y}{x} \right|}^{- 1} \\
& \le 1 + \frac {1}{2 - 1} \\
& = 2.
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\left| \frac {( x + y ) ( {x}^{2} + {y}^{2} )}{{x}^{2} - x y + {y}^{2}} \right|
\le \left| x + y \right| \cdot \left| \frac {{x}^{2} + {y}^{2}}{{x}^{2} - x y + {y}^{2}} \right| \le 2 \left| x + y \right|,
$$
where
$$
\left| x + y \right| \le \left| x \right| + \left| y \right| \le \sqrt {( {1}^{2} + {1}^{2} ) \, ( {\left| x \right|}^{2} + {\left| y \right|}^{2} )} = \sqrt {2 \, ( {x}^{2} + {y}^{2} )}.
$$
Let $\delta = \varepsilon / 4$.
